# Filling up the page with tikz pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a block with tikz and fill the page with it like a sheet music page. In particular I would like to make a page filled with tin whistle shape which will then be filled with a pen after being printed. Can I do this with tikz?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\tikzfill}

\begin{lrbox}{\tikzfill}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
  \draw (1,1) circle (.5);
  \draw (.3,.3) -- (2.7,1.7);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

\newcommand{\fillpage}{%
  \clearpage\begingroup\lineskip=0pt
  \vspace*{-\topskip}
  \xleaders\hbox to\textwidth{\xleaders\hbox{\usebox\tikzfill}\hfill}\vfill
  \endgroup\clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\fillpage

\end{document}
```

[image]